# How do I evenly distribute some time?

Tags: uniform-distribution

Here's my problem. I have a device (ozone generator) which produces 10g of ozone per hour, or 2.77778 milligrams per second (I think). I need to be able to control the production per hour by pulsing the machine on and off to achieve an even rate.

How do I figure out the required rate of pulsing?

So if I can figure out the required amount of seconds to produce the required amount of ozone, how do I evenly distribute those seconds over an hour?

Comment: I can't find a tag I actually like for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's pick an example: I want to generate $3.1$ grams of ozone per hour.  This is $0.31$ of the full-time output.

What we'll do is, for each second, accumulate $0.31$ into an 'accumulator' and then when that value reaches $1$, we'll emit for a second, subtract $1$, and continue.  So:

- At the start of second $0$, it's at $0$, we add $0.31$, getting $0.31$
- At the start of second $1$, we add $0.31$, getting $0.62$
- At the start of second $2$, we add $0.31$, getting $0.93$
- At the start of second $3$, we add $0.31$, getting $1.24$ -- but this is above $1$!  So for second $3$, we turn on the emitter, and we subtract $1$, to get $0.24$
- We continue in this fashion: second $4$ gets us to $0.55$, second $5$ to $0.86$, second $6$ to $1.17$, so turn on the emitter for this second, so down to $0.17$.
- We'll emit again at seconds $9, 16, 19, 22, 25, 29, 32, 35, 38, 41, 45, 48, 51, 54$, and $58$, through the first minute.

Further reading: [Bresenham's Line Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm), [Dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither)

---

Alternatively: since we want $0.31$ of the time to be emitting, that's $1/3.226$ of the time, so we can do "wait 2.226 seconds, emit for one second" over and over and that works too.

Comment: Thank you, this is brilliant! You may have gathered I'm not well versed in maths, would you please explain what you're doing in the edit? I'll be using this solution (or a variant) in some control software for the system and this seems slightly easier to translate.

Comment: so, $1/0.31 \approx 3.226$; so we want the thing on for $1$ second every $3.226$ seconds.  So, subtract 1 from that and we have the time spent not active during those seconds.

Comment: Thanks for making it so easy for me to understand, much appreciated.